# Hphantom of minus sign in math mode

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I would like to align the parenthesis in following two equations using `\hphantom`

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$d\cdot i\hphantom{j}\qquad\hphantom{-}\;(\ldots)$\\
$d\cdot j\hphantom{i}\qquad-(\ldots)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

I know I could use the `align` environment. But I was wondering if it is possible to fix this easily by understanding which whitespace is missing.

Comment: `\hphantom` doesn't take into account spaces around sign `-`. For test compare `$d\cdot i\hphantom{j}\qquad\hphantom{-}(\ldots)$\\
$d\cdot j\hphantom{i}\qquad{-}(\ldots)$` with your MWE. With otherword, to `-` in `\hphantom` you should add those spaces (~`\,\;`)

Comment: `\hphantom{{}-{}}` and no `\;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\mathbin{}`

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$d\cdot i\hphantom{j}\qquad\mathbin{\hphantom{-}}(\ldots)$\\
$d\cdot j\hphantom{i}\qquad-(\ldots)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Spacing_in_math_mode

> For **relational** operators, such as < , > and =, LaTeX establishes
>   `\thickmuskip` space. But for **binary** operators such as +, - and x, the
>   `\medmuskip` space is set. The difference is almost unnoticeable.
>
> You can force the spacing used in binary or relational operators, so
>   you can define your own.

```
\begin{align*}
34x^2a \mathbin{\#} 13bc \\
34x^2a \mathrel{\#} 13bc
\end{align*}
```

> The previous example sets a particular spacing before and after # by using **\mathrel** (relational) and **\mathbin** (binary) commands.